# PHP Updated profile picture doesn't appear in user's profile after refresh

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

So the image is uploaded successfully in the /uploads folder, and also the name is saved in mySQL database within the user's id corresponding.

**upload.php**

```
    $id = $_SESSION['user']['id'];
    $stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = :id');
    $stmt->execute(array('id' => $id));
    $result = $stmt->fetchAll();
if ( count($result) ) {
    foreach($result as $row) {
    }
} else {
    echo "No rows returned.";
}
try {
    $stmt = $db->prepare('UPDATE users SET picture="'.$target_file.'" WHERE id="'.$id.'"');
    $stmt->execute(array(
        ':target_file' => $target_file
    ));
    sleep(5);
    header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
    header("Location: page-profile.php");
    exit();
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

after the redirection it goes here and displays a broken img

**page-profile.php**

```
<div class="col-md-4 text-center">
    <img class="img-circle img-thumbnail avatar avatar-original" 
    src="<?php echo $result[0]['picture']?>">
</div>
```

The really strange thing is that, when I click somewhere in the code (without changing the code) in PhpStorm, and then go back and refresh the page with the broken image (which is 404 by the browser)...the image is magically found and everything is ok.

I struggled too much time now to find the reason, so any help or will be highly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: check the server access log to see if your browser actually sends out a request for that image. maybe it's caching a previously failed attempt.

Comment: What does the path of `$target_file` look like?

Comment: This `$db->prepare('UPDATE users SET picture="'.$target_file.'" WHERE id="'.$id.'"')` is incorrect. Should be `:target_file` and `$id` should be being bound as well.

Comment: I stopped the cache in Chrome's devTools, same thing.

used this also
`header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0");`
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
header("Pragma: no-cache");

Comment: @camelCase  this is the begining of **upload.php ** 

`require_once "config.php";
$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename(time()."_".$_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);`


@chris85 Well they are working as supposed, I have saved path string in the MySQL where I wanted.